# Cannot insert into mongo using mongoImport

Tags: mongodb, import

I am trying to insert a json file into mongo using mongo import

this is my first try:

```
mongoimport --file someorders.json --type json --db test --collection someorders
```

I get the following error:

```
exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON is too large: code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Expecting '{': offset:0
```

Then I tried:

```
mongoimport --file someorders.json --type json --db test --collection someorders --jsonArray
```

And the I get the following error:

```
exception:JSONArray file too large
warning: log line attempted (16384k) over max size(10k), printing beginning and end ... { 
... prints some of the json
ERROR: encountered 1 error(s)
```

Comment: how many records does your json file has ? looks like there is a single record in the json file and its stored as an array and that exceeds the max limit for mongodb.

Comment: did you exported it using `jsonArray` that you decided to import it that way? can you dump and restore it instead of export and import to see if it's working? what is the size of the file?

Comment: @user641887 Supposedly it has 200.000 records. Perhaps there is a problem with the json file? This was a file given to me and I am suppose to do some queries on it.